# Duplicate data in table

Tags: sql, insert

I read some answered questions but they don't help me!
This is my table:

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t_status](
[student_id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[les_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[year_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[status] [bit] NULL,
[Number_of_fail] [int] NULL,
```

I want prevent duplicate  data if their student_id and les_id were equal.
How can I do it,
I don't have much info about triggers but I tried this one that didn't work!

```
        ALTER TRIGGER Trigger1
ON dbo.t_status
FOR INSERT
AS

declare @stu_id nvarchar(50)
declare @les_id int
Declare @Count int 

select @stu_id=student_id,@les_id = les_id From inserted


Select @Count=Count(student_id ) From t_status where les_id=@les_id and student_id=@stu_id
group by student_id

if @Count>1
delete From t_status where student_id =@stu_id
```

Comment: compound primary key on student_id and les_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want prevent duplicate data if their student_id and les_id were equal. how can do it,

This is simple enough to do with `UNIQUE KEY CONSTRAINT` on these two columns than using a trigger.

```
ALTER TABLE t_status
ADD CONSTRAINT T_Status_Unique_StudentId_LesId UNIQUE (student_id, les_id)
```

Triggers are meant for enforcing more complex integrity constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Make a composite/compound primary key, there are plenty of examples:

http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/tip241027/i02create.xml

google is your friend...